# How to enable drupal libraries API

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I have downloaded and extracted libraries API as it is

```
sites/all/libraries
```

but seems not working my dependency library PHPExcel. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you download and enable the libraries module also? This module has to be installed under "sites/all/modules" folder (according to your setup).

Inside "sites/all/libraries" you have to put the library (PHPExcel) not the module.